# Spring Encrypt Values from Properties File

Tags: properties, spring-security

I am currently using a `UserDetailsService` to get values from a user file:

```
<bean id="userDetailsService"  class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.memory.InMemoryDaoImpl">
<property name="userProperties" value="users.properties"/>
</bean>
```

My properties file is meant to be edited by the admin and the username passwords are not encrypted:

```
bob=bobpassword
alice=alicepassword
```

Now, since I use a `PasswordEncoder` in my application, I need to encrypt the passwords and add them to the `UserDetails`. This can be done somewhere in the code, but is not very handy in my opinion.

I found the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with the method `convertPropertyValue(String value)`, which can be overridden.

From what I understand, it should be possible to load the properties file into the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, where the properties could be encrypted in the `convertPropertyValue` method and then loaded by the `UserDetailsService`. Is that possible to do? If yes, hints would help me, otherwise I'd appreciate to see an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Jasypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721069/application-connect-to-database/7721160#7721160), it is a java library which allows the developer to add basic encryption capabilities to his/her projects with minimum effort, and without the need of having deep knowledge on how cryptography works.

You can see how to configure it with Spring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721069/application-connect-to-database/7721160#7721160)

As an alternative, you may also implement your own `propertyPersister` to do the (d)encryption:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="propertiesPersister">
        <bean class="com.mycompany.MyPropertyPersister" />
    </property>        
</bean>
```

Take a look at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423135/how-to-use-encrypted-password-in-apache-basicdatasource?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you expect can be found in 
http://kayalvizhiameen.blogspot.in/2014/04/handling-obfuscated-property-values-in.html