# Keep DB passwords out of spring-servlet.xml file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Here is how my DB config looks currently

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.test" />
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://ip-xxxx.ec2.xxx.com:3306/db" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="user" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean >
```

I want to take the DB properties out of here and put them in tomcat's web.xml file or even from a config file. I am using Spring JPA. How do I do it?

Comment: Use the JNDI datasources integrated in your container, then use the JNDI url in JPA.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Use Google... http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32884938/3641067

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to yout context file!

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="config.properties">
    </property>
</bean>
```

create config.properties in src/main/resources and store user name password as

```
 mongodb.username=mongodbuser
 mongodb.password=morebites
```

now you can refer username and password as

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<beans:property name="url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://ip-xxxx.ec2.xxx.com:3306/db" />
<beans:property name="username" value="${mongodb.username}" />
<beans:property name="password" value="${mongodb.password}" />
```