# Using encrypted property file with Spring

Tags: java, spring, encryption, properties-file

I have the following use case :

1. I have a property file, say `test.properties`
2. This property file needs to be encrypted as this has some confidential data.
3. I have a utility through which i can encrypt the property file.

Is there a way I can use Spring to inject the values from this property file to my class?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249880/spring-encrypt-values-from-properties-file

Comment: @R4J That's asking to encrypt values *in* a property file instead of encrypting the property file in totality if I'm reading the other question correctly. Still, for this specific use case ("it has **some** confidential data") it could provide an answer. Still, not a dupe.

Comment: First thing to wonder: where would Spring find the decryption key?

Comment: @Vyomkesh i did it and actively using it in mu project for encryting db pasword etc. . Im using spring boot but it should be similar with spring as well. Im outside now, but later today i'll post an answer.

Comment: Also, for spring boot, you can look to this.https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/tree/master/jasypt-spring-boot

Comment: I suggest Jasypt Follow the answer by tolitius http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249880/spring-encrypt-values-from-properties-file

Answer (score 0):

The real question is, how are you protecting the key? If someone has access to the key, they can decrypt the properties file.

Even if you keep the key in an HSM, the user that can utilize the HSM can decrypt the properties file, so what's the point?

Create an O/S user to run your application as. Run the application as that user. Only let that user access the properties file. That's the best you can do.