# Passing encrypted properties to spring context

Tags: spring, encryption, properties, system

I never seen this but I wondering if somebody has come across. Having a web server which access a database. I want to pass the database password encrypted and have spring context decrypting it before setting the datasource. I know the spring security can do some of this like using a salt file in the web server, etc.

The challenge here is that I don't want to give a clear user,password,url to the web server team. Just an encrypted password and have spring decrypted before using it.

Is there something like this already? I know I could code something but is it already done?

Thanks

Comment: Already answered in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/storing-private-asymmetric-key-in-application-binary/ ?

Comment: @AngerClown I got 3/4th and I did not see the question reflected, but I think the answers could be surprisingly similar.

Comment: Hi Fabio & welcome. Would the encrypted password have less access to the database then the plain password? If that's not the case, then your encrypted password does not provide any security, it's basically a new, less readable, plain password.

Comment: I actually found the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423135/how-to-use-encrypted-password-in-apache-basicdatasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found exactly what I was looking for in this thread:

[How to use encrypted password in apache BasicDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423135/how-to-use-encrypted-password-in-apache-basicdatasource)
Here are the details from jasyp http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html

Answer (score 4):

By using an org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties object, an application would be able to correctly read and use a .properties file like this:

```
 datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/reportsdb
 datasource.username=reportsUser
 datasource.password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)
```

Note that the database password is encrypted (in fact, any other property could also be encrypted, be it related with database configuration or not).

More information :

http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html

Comment: why arent you using spring. datasource.password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm) but datasource.password ?

Comment: The post is old , where it's using Hibernate as a provider you can use spring.<> if you are on Spring Boot or latest versions of Spring .

Answer (score 0):

This problem and solution to it is explained here..([link](http://kayalvizhiameen.blogspot.in/2014/04/handling-obfuscated-property-values-in.html))

db.Properties.

```
#driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
#url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
#username=ITEM_INVENTORY
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ITEM_INVENTORY?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

username=root
```

1. Encrypt db.Properties

   ```
     ##password=cGFzc3dvcmQ=
     password=cm9vdA==
   ```

The spring beans configuration for the datasource would look like this
(here you may use only password part)

1. spring-beans.xml

   ```
   <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="db#[driverClassName]" />
       <property name="url" value="db#[url]" />
       <property name="username" value="db#[username]" />
       <property name="password" value="encryptedDb#[password]" />
    </bean>  
    <bean id="dbPropertyPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
    <property name="locations">  
        <list>  
          <value>classpath:db.properties</value>  
        </list>  
     </property>  
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="db#[" />
        <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]" />  
     </bean>  
     <bean id="encryptedDbPropertyPlaceholder"  class="com.inventory.api.util.DecryptPropertyConfigurer">  
       <property name="locations">  
          <list>  
             <value>classpath:encryped_db.properties</value>  
          </list>  
       </property>  
       <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="encryptedDb#[" />  
       <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]" /&gt;  
     </bean>
   ```

And so on.. please refer given link for more information..

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Adding the same link to often might be seen as spam.