# Encrypting properties file and persistence xml

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, spring-data, jasypt

I am trying to encrypt all the plain text keys and passwords in my J2EE application. 
I am trying to find out the best way to do so.

I understand that JASYPT has a very good library and utility for encrypting properties file,but doesn't seem to work in case of persistence.xml, which has all db usernames and passwords.

Following is the development stack:

1. Spring MVC
2. Spring
3. Spring DATA JPA
4. Hibernate
5. MYSQL and POSTGRESS DB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933067/passing-encrypted-properties-to-spring-context

Comment: Please don't quote arbitrary sections of your question. Very annoying to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasypt itself has a good solution for the above problem.

By using an org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties object, an application would be able to correctly read and use a .properties file like this:

```
 datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/reportsdb
 datasource.username=reportsUser
 datasource.password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)
```

Note that the database password is encrypted (in fact, any other property could also be encrypted, be it related with database configuration or not).

More information :

http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html

http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Database+Encryption+with+Jasypt-Hibernate