# Apache Ant read build content in memory

Tags: java, ant

Is it possible for Ant to read "build.xml" from memory?

The thing is, we need to read encrypted build.xml from disk, decrypt it in memory (without writing to disk), and pass the decrypted content in memory to Ant, so that Ant can start the build.

Any suggestions or code snippets would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious.. why   ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt Ant build file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452216/encrypt-ant-build-file)

Answer (score 0):

Ant [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html) has an example for creating target and running it.

Since you cannot create temporary file, one option to parse the file, re-create the project structure (just like [ProjectHelper](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/~br=trunk/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/ProjectHelper.java?r=1586262) doing from a file)

Comment: it's a little bit too vague, i'm digging into the source code also, and don't know how to pass the content in memory to "Project".

If possible, please also show the working code.